# What algorithm to use to normalize someone's face on image?

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing

Is there any algorithm implemention available to normalize a face on image making to appear smooth skin. This feature may already be part of some of the photos editing software, but I was looking for actually implementation  or explanation how to implement such algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: I do not know a direct answer to your question, but with regards to the photo-editing process, I tend to use 'clarity' in Photoshop to provide a general smoothness. It's pretty crude but does the job for generally head-shots. It's no good for portrait shots where you would need to apply fixes to blemishes and suchlike.

Answer (score 1):

If you could provide an example it would be easier to answer. Simple smoothing could be achived by using low-pass convolution filters (I would recommend Gaussian filter), or by median filter.

If you would like to perform these operations on the skin only, you need first to segmentate your image (I'm not sure but OpenCV might have some skin-detector included, google for skin detection) than perform the smoothing and copy back the result to the original image.

Comment: I am not worried about detecting skin or face at the moment. When I see some people's photo I noticed their face skin image has been "normalized" giving them a beautiful smooth looking face. I am not sure what it has been done to the image. I am assuming there is some kind of image normalization has been applied to it.

Comment: It's an easy-to-read introduction to filters http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/filtops.htm, I recommend to read median and gauissan filter sections.

Answer (score 1):

I have found bilateral filtering to smooth faces in a gentle way. See the result using the command `BilateralFilter` in Mathematica (cf. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BilateralFilter.html):

[image]

Wikipedia's links may be a starting point to better understand the theory:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter

Answer (score 0):

Yea, Bilateral filter is pretty useful for that. 
Here's a [review](http://imageprocessingblog.com/bilateral-filtering/) and a link to Matlab implementation